# Ionic2 Angular2 HTTP error

Tags: angular2-http

when I execute POST, PUT or DELETE request, I track two http calls 
the first Request Method:OPTIONS and second with my request method (Status Code:500)
PS: I haven't problem with GET method.
Thank you

```
 @Injectable()
export class UtilisateurService {
  url:string;
  _http:Http;
  headers:Headers;
  options:RequestOptions;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this._http=http;
      this.url='http://localhost:8080/todo/user/';
      this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, DELETE, PUT');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers })
  }

 addUser(user:Object): Observable<Response> {
let data = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)
 console.log('adduser '+data)
 return this._http.post(this.url+'add', data,this.options).map(res =>  <Object> res.json())
   .do(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(this.handleError)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs for 500 errors, this is most likely a problem in your backend code.